# If your body was destroyed while in a homunculus via Magic Jar, would the homunculus die?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells

If your body was destroyed while in a homunculus via Magic Jar, would the homunculus die?

For class and story reasons I need my body to be destroyed while in someone or something else's body.
Would it be possible to use Magic Jar on a homunculus of my own creation?
If so, would I die when the body is destroyed because

> If the creature’s master is slain, the homunculus also dies, and its body swiftly melts away into a pool of ichor.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say no. Even if your body is destroyed, you aren't actually dead yet.

> If the spell ends while you are in the magic jar, you return to your body (or die if your body is out of range **or destroyed**).

(Emphasis mine.)

However, when the spell wore off (after 1 hour/level or when dispelled), you would automatically die when you attempted to return to the nonexistent body:

> If the spell ends while you are in a host, you return to your body (or die, if it is out of range of your current position)...

At this point the homunculus would die as well and its body would disintegrate as you described.

All that being said, you should also ask your DM about this before relying on it. The book doesn't give an explicit answer and they might interpret things differently.